# Convert grib (grb2) precipitation band to visible PNG

Tags: gdal-translate, grib

I'have been trying to convert band 7 (precipitation) of a grib file (you can [download](http://www.empresasenlinea.info/pub/tmp/grib.grb2) it if you like) to a visible PNG image which I can load via KML into a google maps viewer I have.

The precipitation of the grib displays just as I'd like to see it inside quantum gis if in Layer properties I choose to render band 7 as single band gray with a pseudocolor color map.  Furthermore specifying 0 for nodata values.

I have tried using this command with gdal (version 1.9.2-2~precise4):

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of PNG -b 7 grib.grb2 grib.png
```

but the resulting grib.png 's size is just 295 Bytes and it is just transparent when opened in a viewer.

I need someone to explain to me how to do this and why.  And if you know other command-line tools which work to convert this file, that'll help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG is can only use 8 and 16 bit unsigned data types.  Your grib is float64 (always).  use gdalinfo to get the min/max for the band (-stats) and the -scale option int gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of png -ot Byte -b 7 -scale GRIB_MIN GRIB_MAX 1 255 grib.grb2 test.png
```

Comment: Excellent kyle, using gdalinfo -stats I got GRIB_MIN=0 and GRIB_MAX=0.022, replaced, executed and produced a nice png.

Do you think there is a way to specify in that command another color scale than gray, like the pseudocolors of qgis?  How would you modify this command to get those colors.

Comment: For your case, you don't have to supply the source min max, and the destination defaults to 0-255:

    gdal_translate -of png -ot Byte -b 7 -scale  grib.grb2 test.png

Comment: Sorry, I should have put this question after your comment: Do you think there is a way to specify in that command another color scale than gray, like the pseudocolors of qgis?  Maybe using a color table file? How would you modify this command to get colors instead of gray tones?

Comment: @user2723476 did you ever get an answer to this follow up question? I've opened a related question myself here on stackexchange. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359849/convert-grib-to-image-using-custom-color-scale